# After 600 length check for closest dot(".") and then remove all text after the dot

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to do is to remove all text after closest dot `(".")` only after text have passed length  of `600`. so lets say a div tag have 5432 text length I want it to display only the text before closest dot`(".")` after 600 text length.

Here is what I have done so far.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dM7Vd/2/)

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: you want to display text between 600 and the index of first dot`.` after 600? or everything until first dot`.` after 600?

Comment: everything until first dot '.' after 600 length

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code can be simplified using [.indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp).

To get part of string you can use [.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) or [.substr()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp).

```
var string = $('#object-full-description').text().trim();

var place = string.indexOf('.', 600);
if (place >= 0)
{
    $('#object-full-description').text(string.substring(0, place));
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dM7Vd/3/).

**Update**. For saving HTML structure you can use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of `.text()`:

```
var string = $('#object-full-description').html();

var place = string.indexOf('.', 600);
if (place >= 0)
{
    $('#object-full-description').html(string.substring(0, place));
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dM7Vd/6/).

Comment: This removes the <br> and <H2> tags is there any solutions to be able to keep have same html structure while changing the text?

Comment: @Obsivus yes, you can use `.html()` for this. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dM7Vd/6/).

Comment: Thank you! Great explanation! I changed to (0, place + 1) to get the dot displayed aswell.

Comment: deleted my answer and +1 this :)

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal you've actually made first my answer with score more than "2", thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var stuff = $('#object-full-description').text().trim();
char = stuff.replace(/^([^]{600}[^.]*\.)[^]*$/, "$1");
console.log(stuff);
```

Regent's code is also elegant.

Answer (score 0):

A little shorter, and +1 so the (".") is also there...

```
$('#object-full-description').html(function(i,t){
    var cut = t.indexOf(".", 600);
    return t.substring(0, cut + 1);
});
```